# Remove language-xxx when converting markdown to html using showdown

Tags: markdown, showdown

I would like to convert markdown files to HTML files using [showdown.js](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown), I intend to use the resulted HTML with [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) for syntax highlighting feature

My code example on markdown file

````
```bash
# whatever here
```
````

The result after conversion from markdown file to HTML

```
<pre>
    <code class="bash language-bash">
        # whatever here
    </code>
</pre>
```

**Questions**

1. How to remove `prefix-bash` from the `class` attribute because `highlight.js` only needs `class='bash'` for correcting syntax highlighting (I've tried with `showdown.getOptions()` I have seen no related options to setup)
2. I'm also curious that most markdown parser usually put `language-` in front of the **language** name itself by default (`class="language-bash"` instead of only `class="bash"`, how this be useful ?

Thanks everyone

Comment: The `language-` prefix is used because the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-code-element) recommends it. As I recall, Highlight.js can accept either form (with or without the prefix). Regardless, the prefix is useful because its clear which class is defining the language. Other classes could also be assigned to the element for other purposes (set line numbers or other features, etc).

Comment: My point is that if a syntax highlighter can't work with the `language-` prefix (as suggested by the HTML5 Spec), then that should be considered a bug with the syntax highlighter.

Comment: thanks @waylan, that has clarified me a lot :)